# How to burst yeoman index.html cache

Tags: angularjs, caching

When I deploy a new version of my Angular app, the old version still persist. Only, the workaround which is fixing is a "hard" refresh on the browser.  (This is not an acceptable solution).

I am using Yeoman (generator-angular) for my project. I looked at the `Gruntfile.js` and see that it executes a task that renames everything during build including images, js, css.  Only file that is not being renamed is `index.html`.  What can I do to `index.html` so that browser will load this file instead of using the cached version?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 7):

You can modify in your server config to tell browsers to not cache by setting `Cache` and `Expires` header for response. I'm giving you an example of Nginx:

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
}
```

Here we are responding `index.html` with headers that will prevent browsers from caching the `index.html` and the browsers will always get the fresh copy. Now, Grunt is already renaming the JS and CSS files based on the content then it will be refreshed automatically.

Of course, the above example is for `Nginx` configuration. You can achieve it for your web server.

Comment: Could you edit the post to add a semicolon at the end of `add_header Cache-Control "no-store"`? That the line yields `add_header Cache-Control "no-store";`. Otherwise the code breaks 