# How to Update script files in the browser immediately. when I updated scripts in the server

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, server, browser-cache

I am working on a web application I updated the code In server when coming to the browser it is loading old files only when I try with hard refresh multiple times it is loading new files   I tried with meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

---

```
window.location.reload();
```

But it is not working.

I am maintaining the version for script files and CSS files. for version management and minification I am using grunt.

For existing users who are already in my application (live users/users who are regular). The script is not updating to check the version how I can update the existing script in the browser

As per my knowledge browser is rendering script from browser cache but I don’t know when it gets the script from the server

The same issue with CSS also.

Comment: Have a look at this answer which details various things you can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593331/1663821 but appending a version number to the script is one of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should append a timestamp to css/js files.
Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/1.js?v=1234455"/>
```

Use this approach:

```
<script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='//site.com
    /js.js?v=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

This way src will be unique each page load so that new js will be loaded.