# To clear cache for angular application which method is best using angular 10 on production

Tags: angular

I have already applied a technique provided by angular
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=dev --aot=true --buildOptimizer=true --outputHashing=all

for fix the caching issue still facing caching issue.....

so I search below 2 solutions for caching issue fix

```
window.location.reload(true)
window.location.href=window.location.href




<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I have already this tags in my index.html file

In short, I want to clear the cache of index.html on my angular build deployment
I have found above two answers which I should use to clear the cache (like ctrl +f5)

Comment: This may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851243/how-to-make-index-html-not-to-cache-when-the-site-contents-are-changes-in-angula/34851492

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">  I have already applied this tag on my index.html file

Comment: Then you need to "tell your web-server" to not cache the index.html as well

Comment: My portal is deployed on azure web app service and in one of thread I found  WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Never  If I will  use it what will be the impact can any body tell me because Its production site I just want to be more clear  do you have idea @JacopoSciampi